# Handling arrays of classes

Tags: c++

I came across this problem where you will have to create a database kind of program which stores the scores of various teams based on their win and loss points under the team name a string. But having an array of classes and searching through the set to find the exact team name and modifying the score is very slow and time consuming. Is there a better and efficient way to do this?

Comment: You could use a map to index the team names http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: Once the list is sorted a binary search should be quite fast.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: did you mean "array of objects" instead of "array of classes" ? or is it a set? Please provide a [mcve]. Code speaks more than thousand words

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map is a good reference for `std::map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map` will work good for this. Something like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // team name and scores
    // std::map has std::pair as its elements
    std::map<std::string, int> teams{ {"team1", 300}, {"team2", 500}, {"team3", 100} };

    teams["team2"] = 0; // set team2's score to 0
    teams["team4"] = 1000; // new team with score of 1000

    for (const std::pair<std::string, int>& pair : teams) // auto will work
        std::cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
team1: 300
team2: 0
team3: 100
team4: 1000
```

Answer (score -1):

My C++ is not recent but why not create a second class which provides the functionality of storing the collection/array of object classes and provide the clean functionality of finding the object from within the collection and passing it back as the return parameter?

```
class teams {
    int x;
public:
    team getTeamByName(char teamName[20]);
    // Add other methods to add or remove teams...

private:
    team gTeams[10];
};

team getTeamByName(char pTeamName[20]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < gTeams.length; i++) {
        if gTeams[i].teamName = pTeamName
            return gTeams[i];
    }
    return null;
};
```

As I said my c++ is a bit rusty as not touched it in a while but creating a wrapper class to encompass the search functionality makes code cleaner and reduces repetitive code.

The above class would also lend itself to managing the list of teams too as adding code to add teams to the array and removing them will also assist in creating clean and easy to read code.

Please excuse the code above if there is syntactical errors but I hope it gives you the base to write it correctly and no doubt someone will point out any issues failing that.

P

Comment: Syntactical errors can be checked with a compiler. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c06904d1ca3cb88

__main.cpp:4:5: error: 'team' does not name a type; did you mean 'teams'?
     team getTeamByName(char teamName[20]);
     ^~~~
     teams
main.cpp:8:5: error: 'team' does not name a type; did you mean 'teams'?
     team gTeams[10];
     ^~~~
     teams
main.cpp:11:1: error: 'team' does not name a type; did you mean 'teams'?
 team getTeamByName(char pTeamName[20]) {
 ^~~~
 teams
main.cpp:17:2: warning: extra ';' [-Wpedantic]
 };
  ^__

Comment: Having such a class is probably a good idea but has nothing to do with OP’s question, which was about efficiency. Your code doesn’t change that aspect.

Comment: team was the assumption of the class already created by the OP, this was not meant to be a full solution but more of a pointer in the right direction.